# Only accept propertys inserted into an interface using typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm recently starting my journey with typescript and I'm developing an application using express + typescript.

I have this controller:

```js
import { Request, Response } from 'express'
import PartialUserUpdateService from '../services/PartialUserUpdateService'

class PartialUserUpdateController {
  async handle (request: Request, response: Response): Promise<Response> {
    const id : number = +request.params.id
    const partialUserContent = request.body

    const partialUserUpdateService = new PartialUserUpdateService()
    const user = await partialUserUpdateService.execute({ userId: id, partialUserContent })

    return response.status(200).json(user)
  }
}

export default new PartialUserUpdateController()
```

And this service:

```js
import { getRepository } from 'typeorm'
import UserSchema from '../entities/user.schema'

interface IPartialUserUpdate {
  name?: string;
  email?: string;
  age?: number;
  cpf?: string;
}

interface IPartialUserDTO {
  userId: number;
  partialUserContent: IPartialUserUpdate;
}

class PartialUserUpdateService {
  async execute ({
    userId,
    partialUserContent
  }: IPartialUserDTO): Promise<IPartialUserUpdate> {

    const userRepository = getRepository(UserSchema)
    const user = await userRepository.findOne(userId)

    if (!user) throw new Error('User doesnt exists')
    await userRepository.update({ id: user.id }, userContent)
    return partialUserContent
  }
}

export default PartialUserUpdateService
```

I'm trying to make `partialUserContent` object only able to receive properties declared in the interface `IPartialUserUpdate`

How can I check properties and types explicitly and report an error if any type is different?

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link to code)](https://tsplay.dev/WP5EEw), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. There's [a way to do this with object literals](https://tsplay.dev/NBz3dN), but [you can always pass a pre-created object, avoiding the error](https://tsplay.dev/mbkP2W)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. There's [a way to do this with object literals](https://tsplay.dev/NBz3dN), but [you can always pass a pre-created object, avoiding the error](https://tsplay.dev/mbkP2W).

Such type guards in TypeScript are designed to ensure that the later usage of such values will not cause any silly errors. In other words, if your function uses `foo.prop`, then `foo` is better to have property `prop`, – everything else is outside of the scope of the type guarding.